# How can I pass multiple records from one form to another form in C#?

Tags: c#

I have 2 forms, `form1` and `form2`. Whenever I double click on a cell of datagrid in form1, it will go form 2 and there I am displaying some items and price of them in a datagrid. I am selecting one row there and that value is passing form 1 datagridview. but I want to pass second valu that also over writing first passed value of form 1. I want to add that in next row. What do I have to do?

Here is my code of form 2

```
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)// loading data to datagrid from database file
    {
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(@"select     brnDb.compname as [company name], brnDb.catname as [category Name],     itemDB.fullname as [Item Name], itemDb.itmbyp as [Buying Price], itemDB.itmdlrp [Dealer Price],itemDB.itmmrp as [MRP],itemDb.itmunit as [Unit Of Measure], itemDB.itmml [Liters], itemDB.itmgr[KGs], itemDb.itmpc[Units] from brnDB inner join itemDb on brnDb.brname=itemDB.brname order by itemDB.fullname asc", con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        sda.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    }
```

passing selected row with a button click to form 1

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 b = new Form1(dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[2].Value.ToString(),
                            dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[3].Value.ToString(),
                            dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[4].Value.ToString(),
                            dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[5].Value.ToString());
        b.ShowDialog();
    }
```

Code of form 1

```
 public Form1(string Item_Name, string Buying_Price, string Dealrer_Price, string MRP )
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        int n;


        n = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
        dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[1].Value = Item_Name;
        dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[3].Value = Buying_Price;
        dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[4].Value = Dealrer_Price;
        dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[5].Value = MRP;
    }
```

So value is being passed from form 2 but overwriting in first row each time. But I want to add new row in form1 before passing.Maybe I want to use some loops here but I don't know how. for looping purpose I took declared a integer also. I googled for that but end up with no good result.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a List in form1 which can be accessed in form2.

Define `Form1 b = null;` as global variable

Add `b = new Form1();` Form2_Load function

Add `b.list.Add(dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0]);` to button1_click function before ShowDialog();

Keep only `b.ShowDialog();` line in button1_click function

Add `public List<DataGridViewRow> list = new List<DataGridViewRow>();` to form1

Comment: ok I will do what you told and any prob then I will come here to ask.

Answer (score 0):

We can also have another option is to create static class that have generic list . We can use that list as temporary storage.

```
static class Global
{
    private static List<GridRows> _globalVar = new List<GridRows>();

    public static void ResetGridData()
    {
        _globalVar = new List<GridRows>();
    }
    public static GridRows SetRow
    {
        set { _globalVar.Add(value); }
    }

    public static List<GridRows> GetSetting { get { return _globalVar; } }

    public class GridRows
    {
        public string Cell_1 { get; set; }

        public string Cell_2 { get; set; }

        public string Cell_3 { get; set; }

        public string Cell_4 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This class have public static SetRow setter. Use this setter to save data in global list  which is "_globalVar ".

This class also have method to reset that list in any point. Just call that static method to reset that grid.

**How to use**

This is form2 code that get data and pass to form1.

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        //To reset our temporary store on load
        Global.ResetGridData();
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Send data from form 2 to form 1
        Form1 b = new Form1(dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[2].Value.ToString(),
        dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[3].Value.ToString(),
        dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[4].Value.ToString(),
        dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[5].Value.ToString());
        b.ShowDialog();

    }
}
```

Receive and save data to our global list in form 1

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public Form1(string cell1, string cell2, string cell3, string cell4)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //Save data to our list using global class that
        Global.SetRow = new Global.GridRows()
        {
            Cell_1 = cell1,
            Cell_2 = cell2,
            Cell_3 = cell3,
            Cell_4 = cell4
        };
    }
}
```